# Rhythm Game Note Spawning i Hit Detection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have this rhythm game prototype, and i want to spawn notes so i created a few scripts which I'll provide later, however it doesn't really work, and it's pretty inaccurate. The notes do seem to spawn but when i try to press a button to trigger a "hit", it's like a whole second off, and when i measured the time it takes for the notes to fall down in the script, it's always a little bit off so i can't really seem to make it accurate.

While this system sort of works, and I'm sure i could get it to work eventually I don't really think it's a great way to do it, but i don't really know any good way to do it.

Here's the important scripts:

Level.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class Level : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The data of a note
    struct NoteData
    {
        public float pressTime; // When the note should be perfectly aligned with the button
        public byte track;
    }
    // NoteDatas is just an array of the note infos
    [SerializeField] private NoteData[] noteDatas;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject notePrefab;

    // Notes are instances of Note, which are components of the notePrefab and are spawned in NoteSpawner()
    public static List<Note> notes;

    // 4 GameObjects where the notes spawn 
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] tracks;
    float time = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        notes = new List<Note>();

        // A bunch of notes just for testing
        noteDatas = new NoteData[5];
        noteDatas[0].track = 0;
        noteDatas[0].pressTime = 1;

        noteDatas[1].track = 1;
        noteDatas[1].pressTime = 1.2f;

        noteDatas[2].track = 3;
        noteDatas[2].pressTime = 1.3f;

        noteDatas[3].track = 3;
        noteDatas[3].pressTime = 1.5f;

        noteDatas[4].track = 2;
        noteDatas[4].pressTime = 1.1f;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Countdown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the countdown and then starts the level
    /// </summary>
    public async void Countdown()
    {
        // Placeholder countdown
        Debug.Log("3");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Debug.Log("2");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Debug.Log("1");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Debug.Log("Start!");

        // Start level
        OnStart();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes when the level starts
    /// </summary>
    public void OnStart()
    {
        NoteSpawner();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        time += Time.deltaTime;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Loop for spawning the notes.
    /// </summary>
    async void NoteSpawner()
    {
        // Delay - time between the note spawning and being perfectly in position
        float spawnDelay = 0.81f;

        while (true)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < noteDatas.Length; i++)
            {
                if (noteDatas[i].pressTime - spawnDelay <= time)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Spawned note");

                    SpawnNote(noteDatas[i]);

                    // A terrible way to remove the unused note data.
                    // Probably should just switch it to a list instead.
                    List<NoteData> list = noteDatas.ToList();
                    list.RemoveAt(i);
                    noteDatas = list.ToArray();
                }
            }
            await Task.Delay(1);
        }
    }

    // OnButton() is used by a script called ButtonManager, which triggers this method when a correct button is clicked and passes a variable "track" which is an int from 0-3 indicating which button has been pressed
    public void OnButton(int track)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < notes?.Count; i++)
        {
            if (notes[i].track == track)
            {  
                if (time > notes[i].pressTime - 0.2f || time < notes[i].pressTime + 0.2f)
                {
                    notes[i].OnHit((int)(time * 1000 - notes[i].pressTime * 1000));
                    Debug.Log("Delay: " + (time - notes[i].pressTime) + "\nTime: " + time + "\nPress Time: " + notes[i].pressTime);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Spawns note
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns>The spawned note</returns>
    Note SpawnNote(NoteData data)
    {
        Note note = GameObject.Instantiate(notePrefab).GetComponent<Note>();

        note.transform.SetParent(tracks[data.track].transform);

        note.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(0, 0.55f);
        note.track = data.track;
        note.pressTime = data.pressTime;
        notes.Add(note);

        return note;
    }
}
```

Note.cs

```
using Assets.Scripts.Game;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Note : MonoBehaviour
{
    public const float speed = 1;

    // When the note should be perfectly aligned with the button (in seconds)
    public float pressTime;
    public byte track;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, -speed * Time.deltaTime * 10));

        // When the note is not hit :(
        if (transform.position.y < -6)
        {
            OnMiss();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets triggered when the note has been hit within the time limit
    /// </summary>
    public void OnHit(int delay_ms)
    {
        // ScoreManager is a script that holds the score and score-related methods
        ScoreManager.OnHit(delay_ms);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets triggered when the note's y position is below -6
    /// </summary>
    private void OnMiss()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        Level.notes.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

Sorry if the question is hard to read but i genuinely don't know how to do it really

Comment: its off by a second? im not sure theres enough info but "notes falling?" if they are placed on a track and that track moves at an even speed, they will always come at the exact time you plan as you can calculate the position of distance as a function of how fast the track moves and so how long you expect it to take to get there, eg much like a car, if a car travels at 60mph, in 30 mins it will have done 30, and to do 123miles it will take 123 minutes.  as for being a second out? thaat doesnt make any sense but then I dont think theres whats needed here

Comment: I am pretty sure the 1s delay is a just a bug, but it always seems to be a bit off probably because Time.deltaTime isn't always the same so the notes spawn at slightly different times, which could mess up the hit accuracy calculations

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the delay issue by removing the `void Update()` completely, adding a `startTime` variable which is set in `OnStart()` and changing the time variable to `float time { get { return Time.time - startTime; } }`.

I think the problem was that i was counting the time from the start of the game, when in reality i wanted to start counting it in the OnStart() method.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to make this work in a better way, I'd like to hear it :))